# Failed to resolve entry for package "@material-tailwind/react"

Tags: reactjs

I have installed the Tailwind CSS library successfully in my Vite with React development environment, and it worked fine. However, when I tried to install the Material Tailwind library, I encountered this issue despite following the steps for the installation correctly. Can you please help me find a solution?

The error is:-

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve entry for package "@material-tailwind/react". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
E:/final/final-shop/src/main.jsx
    at packageEntryFailure (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:28708:11)
    at resolvePackageEntry (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:28705:5)
    at tryNodeResolve (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:28436:20)
    at Context.resolveId (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:28197:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.resolveId (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:44164:32)
    at async TransformContext.resolve (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:43880:23)
    at async normalizeUrl (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:41755:34)
    at async file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:41907:47
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async TransformContext.transform (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:41832:13)
    at async Object.transform (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:44240:30)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:54896:29)
    at async viteTransformMiddleware (file:///E:/final/final-shop/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:64291:32
Click outside, press Esc key, or fix the code to dismiss.
You can also disable this overlay by setting server.hmr.overlay to false in vite.config.js.
```

I tried to modify the tailwind.config.js file from this:

```
const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");
 
module.exports = withMT({
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
});
```

to this:

```
import { withMT } from "@material-tailwind/react/utils";
 
module.exports = withMT({
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
});
```

I also attempted to modify the import path of the Material Tailwind file in main.jsx, but it didn't work as expected.

Well, this is main.js file

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-tailwind/react";
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <ThemeProvider>
        <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
)
```

Comment: They broke it https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-tailwind/issues/408. Downgrade to `2.0.5`. It looks like they published a new version whilst forgetting to actually build it before publish :D.